# How to make components change position and size according to the frame size?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I am using java windowbuilder to build a project for my schoolwork. I am having trouble with getting the components to change their positions, when the size of the main JFrame is altered.

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Can you add some code that shows you're trying.

Comment: `JFrame` means you have a _Swing_ application. So you run the application and change the size of the `JFrame` - with the mouse, right? And after you change the size, the GUI doesn't look like you expect it to look. Is this correct?

Comment: @Abra Yes ! Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: As @AlokeT wrote in his comment: _Can you add some code that shows you're trying._ I presume that I will be able to solve your problem after you post your code. Please edit your question and add the code. And make sure you format it using the relevant markup tags. Make sure it is complete code that I can copy and run on my machine.

Comment: `Do you know how to solve this problem ?` - read the tutorial link from the first comment and download the demo code and play with the demo code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mh4k4A0j 
@Abra Here is the link to some of my code

Comment: This line of your code means you are not using a _layout manager_: `RTG.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` So I suggest you remove this line and read up on using layout managers in _Swing_. Look at the link the @MadProgrammer posted.

Comment: @Abra Thank you for the advice ! I will take a look